# How to find tail rows of a data frame that satisfy set criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

An example of my data is structured as follows:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", 
                                      "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill"),  
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      Condition = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", 
                                    "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr"),
                      Location = c("Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", 
                                   "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away"),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 390, 570, 456, 205))
```

I wish to find the tail row for each `Participant` when `Condition` equals Placebo and `Location` equals Home. This will be used to examine the `Power` at the last time point, so I can examine the remaining 10 rows prior. Locating the row number is important for this reason.

I know that I can locate the last row for each `Participant` using:

```
ddply(Individ,.(Participant, Time, Condition),function(x) tail(x,1))
```

However, my actual data frame is 4 million rows in length with over 50 participants and `Power` collected at differing `Time` points. Is there a way that I can quickly do this, that is not computationally expensive?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Individ)`), grouped by 'Participant', use the logical condition ('Condition == 'Placebo' & Location =='Home'`) in 'i' and subset the last observation (`tail(.SD, 1L)`or`.SD[.N]`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Individ)[Condition=='Placebo' & Location=='Home', 
                             tail(.SD, 1L) ,.(Participant)]
#   Participant Time Condition Location Power
#1:        Bill    6   Placebo     Home   450
#2:        Jane    6   Placebo     Home   451
```

If we need the row numbers, we can get it with `.I`

```
setDT(Individ)[Condition=='Placebo' & Location=='Home',
        c(rn = .I[.N],tail(.SD, 1L)) ,.(Participant)]
#    Participant rn Time Condition Location Power
#1:        Bill  6    6   Placebo     Home   450
#2:        Jane 18    6   Placebo     Home   451
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already laid out the logic:

```
Individ %>% mutate(Row = seq_along(Time)) %>% 
    filter(Condition == 'Placebo', Location == 'Home') %>% 
    group_by(Participant) %>% slice(n())
```

Add `Row` numbers with `mutate` and `seq_along()`; `filter` down to rows that suit your conditions; `group_by` participant, for which `slice` pulls out the row that corresponds to the `n`umber of rows for that participant.

For your sample data, it returns:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
Groups: Participant [2]

  Participant  Time Condition Location Power   Row
       (fctr) (dbl)    (fctr)   (fctr) (dbl) (int)
1        Bill     6   Placebo     Home   450     6
2        Jane     6   Placebo     Home   451    18
```

It's not doing significant heavy lifting and is pretty optimized so it should be reasonably quick, but 4 million rows is a lot so you may need to look into `data.table` or storing it as SQL, for which you can use `dplyr` as an interface.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not give me the row number/ location of where the  last row occurs, only the time point.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you wanted row numbers. Updated, and `seq_along()` is very optimized, too.

Comment: Although I accepted the `data.table` solution, your updated answer worked too. Thank you for taking the time to reply.