# How to remove N rows of a data frame, according to conditions

Tags: r

My question follows on from [How to find tail rows of a data frame that satisfy set criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403375/how-to-find-tail-rows-of-a-data-frame-that-satisfy-set-criteria/35403553?noredirect=1#comment58521929_35403553) and as such, my (updated) sample data is structured as:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill"),  
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                      Condition = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr"),
                      Location = c("Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Away", "Away", "Away", "Away"),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 390, 570))
```

I have learnt to find the tail row for each `Participant` across the different `Condition` plus `Location` based on their last occurrence of `Power`. I now wish to delete the last 3 rows from each `Participant` for each `Condition` and `Location`. However, the `Time` collected for each `Participant` and `Condition` differs and therefore I can not delete rows purely based on a standardised `Time`.

How can I quickly iterate through each `Participant` and their respective `Condition`plus `Location` and delete the final 3 rows? My actual data frame is 4 million rows + with over 50 participants so ideally, a solution that iterates over each `Participant` and `Condition` would be desirable.

My anticipated output would be:

```
Output <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Bill"),
                     Time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                     Condition = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr"),
                     Location = c("Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Away"),
                     Power = c(400, 250, 600, 512, 300, 402, 210, 130, 608))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `dplyr`, with `row_number()` and `n()`...

```
library(dplyr)
Individ %>%
  group_by(Participant, Condition, Location) %>%
  filter(row_number() < n() - 2)
```

returns

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: Participant, Condition, Location [4]

  Participant  Time Condition Location Power
       (fctr) (dbl)    (fctr)   (fctr) (dbl)
1        Bill     1   Placebo     Home   400
2        Bill     2   Placebo     Home   250
3        Jane     1      Expr     Home   600
4        Jane     2      Expr     Home   512
5        Jane     3      Expr     Home   300
6        Jane     1   Placebo     Home   402
7        Jane     2   Placebo     Home   210
8        Jane     3   Placebo     Home   130
9        Bill     1      Expr     Away   608
```

Comment: Who knew it would be that easy?! Thank you for the `dplyr` solution.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Individ)`), grouped by 'Participant', 'Condition', and 'Location', we remove the last 3 observations for each combination using `head`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Individ)[, head(.SD, -3) , .(Participant, Condition, Location)]
#   Participant Condition Location Time Power
#1:        Bill   Placebo     Home    1   400
#2:        Bill   Placebo     Home    2   250
#3:        Jane      Expr     Home    1   600
#4:        Jane      Expr     Home    2   512
#5:        Jane      Expr     Home    3   300
#6:        Jane   Placebo     Home    1   402
#7:        Jane   Placebo     Home    2   210
#8:        Jane   Placebo     Home    3   130
#9:        Bill      Expr     Away    1   608
```

---

The equivalent option in `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
Individ %>% 
     group_by(Participant, Condition, Location) %>% 
     do(head(., -3))
#  Participant  Time Condition Location Power
#       (fctr) (dbl)    (fctr)   (fctr) (dbl)
#1        Bill     1      Expr     Away   608
#2        Bill     1   Placebo     Home   400
#3        Bill     2   Placebo     Home   250
#4        Jane     1      Expr     Home   600
#5        Jane     2      Expr     Home   512
#6        Jane     3      Expr     Home   300
#7        Jane     1   Placebo     Home   402
#8        Jane     2   Placebo     Home   210
#9        Jane     3   Placebo     Home   130
```